# Delete object in java from within the class

Tags: java, object

How do I delete a java object from it' class. Let's say I have a class like:

```
class A
{
    int hp;
    public void update()
    {
        if(hp <= 0)
        {
            //here comes the problem. Something like: this.delete(); ??
        }
    }
}
```

and I have an instance in my main method that checks if it should delete itself.

EDIT: In my case 'A' is a windmill class in a 2D RTS. It sits in an ArrayList of windmills and has following methods:

```
init(called when the game starts to load images)

update(this is where i want to delete the object) 

draw(for rendering)
```

Comment: Please define "delete"? Please provide some context, *any* context.

Comment: sth like free up the memory?

Comment: What do you want `delete` to do that the JVM doesn't do for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Java) Remove an instance from memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350505/java-remove-an-instance-from-memory)

Comment: @user2466076 The GC does this for you when it needs to.  There is nothing to do to delete it.

Comment: Why would the JVM delete my object if it doesnt know if i will use it

Comment: lets say A is a sodier and if it gets killed I wand to delete him

Comment: You just have to "delete" any references to our object, then GC should do the rest.

Comment: Because that's what garbage collection means. You also need to consider that deleting an object while it is still running its own code doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: just set the object to null.

Comment: You're giving context in dribs and drabs making this question a painful process of trying to extract information from you, and trying to answer based on the partial information you give. Why not just tell us all relevant information from the get go? Why not give us concrete information? What is the rationale for the question? Are you running out of memory? If so, show your error information and code. Please help us out here.

Comment: @HongWeiWang: you can't set an "object" to null, just variables, and that often isn't enough for this.

Comment: I think you guys are misinterpreting his question. Look at the context from the minimal code he has provided. Assuming `hp` stands for hitpoints, it appears he is trying to manage a `Collection` of `Entity`s, perhaps he wants to remove it from his `Collection`... I don't know.

Comment: @JoshM: as I've already stated in my attempt at an answer.

Comment: You haven't explained why do you want to worry about deleting objects (when the JVM does this for you anyway?)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Fair enough :P

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels well you could if it is defined as an object. It all depends on the context what he means by removing it.

Comment: An object can be freed after there is not more strong references to that object.  i.e. it is deleted when you don't need it any more.

Comment: @HongWeiWang: you're confusing objects with variables. Again you cannot set an object to null, period.

Comment: @HongWeiWang You can set a *reference* to null. Not an object. And nulling references is mostly a waste of time.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I see what you mean, What I am trying to say is that if you set the variable to null, that means you are not using it's memory address any more, so JVM will try to free up the memory.

Comment: @EJP if you have a large object and a long method where setting to `null` would help I would suggest breaking the method so the variable just goes out of scope.

Comment: @HongWeiWang: as stated, this is not a good idea and usually does not work. Best to declare variables in as limited a scope as possible, to have them naturally be freed from all references when no longer needed, and to profile your code so that you can see when it is running into trouble.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't know why that comment is addressed to me.

Comment: I think he wants to remove the object from array.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you but, more than half the examples where it is not a waste of time, there is a better solution such as refactoring.

Comment: yes the object is in an ArrayList which luckily is public and static so the problem is solved. thans for your broad explanation

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've *never* seen an example where it wasn't a waste of time or couldn't be refactored away, but I haven't seen all the examples. Neither have you. 'More than half' is just a guess, and so is 99% as you've stated elsewhere.

Comment: You state, `"yes the object is in an ArrayList which luckily is public and static so the problem is solved."` -- no this is very bad, both your use of public and static modifiers. Please see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to "free up memory" of an object, and unfortunately there is no one-size-fits-all solution. You must null all active references to the object. Again this all depends on context, on what variables refer to your object of interest. Do this and the GC will free the reference, when it decides that GC'ing needs to be done, something we don't have control over, but only can make suggestions to the GC.

---

you state in comment:

> lets say A is a sodier and if it gets killed I wand to delete him

Then remove him from the soldier duty list, possibly a database or ArrayList.

---

Best to declare variables in as limited a scope as possible, to have them naturally be freed from all references when no longer needed, and to profile your code so that you can see when it is running into trouble.

---

You state in comment:

> yes the object is in an ArrayList which luckily is public and static so the problem is solved. thans for your broad explanation

No, this is not correct. The ArrayList should not be static nor public but rather should be a private instance field. Making the field static means that it can not be used in an object-oriented way. Making it public means that any object can mutate it at any time, and in complex programs this can lead to difficult to trace problems and increased cyclomatic complexity. It should be mutable only in a controlled way via public methods of the class that holds it. I'm sorry, but your program design sounds flawed suggesting that you will want to review, refactor, improve it. How, it's hard to say based on snippets of information.

Comment: I haven't thought about it, thanks!

Comment: Terminology please. *Null* all references ... and GC will free the *object.*

Comment: @user2466076 even one reachable, strong reference will keep an object alive as it still might be needed.

Comment: @user2466076 (a) No. (b) Yes. You've been told all this several times.

Comment: the ArrayList is static because its a universal list of instances. It is located in an external file. I use it on many different ocasions so i need it public

Comment: and it is static because only one exists at a time

Comment: @user2466076: your rationale for this need is all wrong. Please read a good book on OOP concepts and Java such as Effective Java by Bruce Eckels to see more on why your current practice is bad. It doesn't matter if you only make one instance. If you want to refactor your code in an MVC fashion, you won't be able to do this easily if it is not OOP compliant for instance. If you want to make your ArrayList notify other fields of changes, to make it what is known as a "bound property", you need to make it private with mutator access only via a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you cannot explicitly delete an object from memory. The nice thing is that this is handled by what we call the "Garbage Collector". When this runs, it goes around finding objects with no references to them and deletes them. Thus, the only thing you can do is remove all references to the object (let them go out of scope, set them to null, whatever) and then wait for the GC to run.

There is no way to force the GC to run, however, you can *technically* "encourage" it to run with the `System.gc()` method. This does not promise that it will run however and is not needed in anything other than edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Even if C++ you have to clean up your pointers/references to an object before you can safely free it's memory.  In Java, this is all you have to do and it does the rest.

> update(this is where i want to delete the object)

This means you want to remove it from your ArrayList.  You can either

- do it immediately, but this requires a reference to the list(s) the object is in.
- or remove dead entries on discovery e.g. when iterating over the list.